# Menu takes over height of child element which causes hopping effect

Tags: html, css

[image: menu hopping]

As you can see it gives a very annoying effect when the submenu is larger than it's parent. I'd like to keep the main-menu in the original height, but I really can't find the part that's responsible for this behaviour. It's a theme that's not built by me, so that makes it even harder to find a solution.

This is the live url: https://testing.sceneryworkshop.com

I'm almost on a mental breakdown here :D So IF anyone could help me out, it would be much appreciated!

As requested some code (I don't think this ads much extra to my post, but it may be). It's Lightspeed HQ which uses Twigg as far as I know. I guessed you'd like to have a Live url to inspect with inspector to see it in action.

```
    <div class="nav-main">
      <ul>
        <li><a>{{ 'Menu' | t }}</a>
          <ul>
            {% for category in shop.categories | limit(10) %}
            <li><a href="{{ category.url | url }}">
              {% if theme.show_category_images %}<span class="img"><img src="{{ category.image | url_image('64x44x2', category.title) }}" alt="{{ category.title }}" width="32" height="22"></span>{% endif %}{{ category.title }}</a>
              {% if category.subs %}
              <ul>
                <li class="strong"><a href="{{ category.url | url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
                {% for category in category.subs %}
                <li><a href="{{ category.url | url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
                  {% if category.subs %}
                  <ul>
                    <li class="strong"><a href="{{ category.url | url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
                    {% for category in category.subs %}
                    <li><a href="{{ category.url | url }}">{{ category.title }}</a>
                      {% if category.subs %}
                      <ul>
                        <li class="strong"><a href="{{ category.url | url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
                        {% for category in category.subs %}
                        <li><a href="{{ category.url | url }}">{{ category.title }}</a></li>
                        {% endfor %}
                      </ul>
                      {% endif %}
                    </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </ul>
                  {% endif %}
                </li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
              {% endif %}
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% if shop.categories | length > 10 %}
            <li><a href="{{ 'catalog' | url }}">{{ 'All categories' | t }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproducible example? Without some code, we can't help you

Comment: Can you share a git link or something else where we can find the entire code to check

Comment: @GangadharGandi You can see it in action on: https://testing.sceneryworkshop.com

Comment: You have this line in your custom.js file:  $(this).parents('ul').css('min-height', $(this).children('ul').outerHeight());      which cause the main ul menu height to be 680px

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Elad! Without you I never found this! You made my day!
Commenting out that part solved the problem!

````
                        $(this).find('li.sub').on('mouseenter', function() {
                            $(this).delay(250).queue(function() {
                                // $(this).parents('ul').css('min-height', $(this).children('ul').outerHeight());
                                $(this).parents('ul:first').addClass('has-hover');
                                $(this).dequeue();
                            });
                        }).on('mouseleave', function() {
                            $(this).parents('ul').removeAttr('style');
                            $(this).parents('ul:first').removeClass('has-hover');
                        });
                    } ```
````